# Vertx multithreaded verticle instance and worker pool size

Tags: java, vert.x

for my vertx app, I am creating and deploying multithreaded verticle having multiple instance , i just want to know if number of instance and worker pool size for that verticle should be same?? Different? With reference if possible , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose of multithreaded worker verticles is to register eventbus consumers and handle messages on worker threads concurrently without having to create as much instances as threads available in the worker pool.

So the answer to your question is: create a single instance, it will use all the worker threads available.

But if you plan something else, don't do it. For example, you can't create HTTP servers on a MT worker verticle.

More importantly, if you're starting a new application, avoid multithreaded worker verticles, they are deprecated and will be completely removed in Vert.x 4.

Comment: in my app , multiple verticles are present(all are multithreaded) which delegates message to another verticle , do processing and return result back ... if I create multiple instance(example 3) for same verticle (multithreaded true) with same number of work pool size for verticle(3) , how does it will differ then single instance verticle ??

Comment: It will change nothing. Anyway if you're doing multithreaded everywhere I'm not sure why you actually an event driven toolkit like Vert.x

Comment: well if I set multithreaded as false then server is not able to handle load ...even if I am having multiple verticle instances are running with large worker pool size